# switch image with another image is same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 images. When I click on an image it should show different content. Now I want also that when I click on the default image switch also image in same position of default image with another image, this for first image and for second image.

I have this code: https://jsfiddle.net/xsywzLp9/

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
    <div class="img image1" content="content1">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2010/11/24/autumn-1_640.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:250px;">
    </div>
    <div class="img image2" content="content2">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/06/25/17/23/landscape-821573_640.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:250px;">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="content content1">
        image content 1
    </div>
    <div class="content content2">
        image content 2
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need javascript given the currenct structure.

Comment: how make this with js ?

Comment: We're not here on SO to write your code for you. We're here to help you with any problems you have with **your** code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but you could wrap the two images in a div:
EDIT : https://jsfiddle.net/xsywzLp9/49/

```
$(".img").click(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $("."+$(this).attr("content")).fadeToggle(true);
    if ($('div').hasClass('image1')){
       $('.image1 img[alt="Mountain View"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Check the jsfiddle.

Comment: tested with my code but not work , tou can try on jsfiddle